# Is there a different function like sscanf to find specific format input fields and save them?

Tags: c

Im using sscanf method in order to find specific format to stdin like this kind of inputs:

My problem is i specified the right regex with sscanf and saved those as wanted into variables but everytime im trying to debug it they are not saved as I want them to be, Even though i checked alot of examples of sscanf usages and what i did seems right to me therefore i came here to ask for advises in order to make it right.
and this is the problem line in my code that i need to get advise on

```
 if (strcmp(gets(currentLine),"q")){
        numOfFields = sscanf(currentLine,
                             "%d%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]%*[\t]%f%*[\t]%f%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]",
                             &studentID, &studentName, &studentAge, &studentGrade, &studentCountry,
                             &studentCity);
```

I've tried using sscanf method and its not returning the right fields that i expected them with my check of the regex, the example like this:

3888914775 Itzel Gardner 21 26 Iran Tehran

it doesn't save the id and name etc.. in the right variable i added it in.

under you can see my code and the expected results.

```
int getAllStudents(){

   int numOfFields=0;
   char currentLine[150]="null";
   int studentCounter=0;
   int studentID;
   float studentAge,studentGrade;
   char studentName[MAX_STRING_FIELD],studentCountry[MAX_STRING_FIELD],
        studentCity[MAX_STRING_FIELD];

 while (1){
    printf("Enter student info. To exit press q, then enter");
    if (strcmp(gets(currentLine),"q")){
        numOfFields = sscanf(currentLine,
                             "%d%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]%*[\t]%f%*[\t]%f%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]%*[\t]%[a-zA-Z -]",
                             &studentID, &studentName, &studentAge, &studentGrade, &studentCountry,
                             &studentCity);

        if (numOfFields  != 6 ) {
            printf("ERROR!");
            break;
        }

        allStudents[studentCounter].studentID=studentID;
        allStudents[studentCounter].studentAge=studentAge;
        allStudents[studentCounter].studentGrade=studentGrade;
        strcpy(allStudents[studentCounter].studentName,studentName);
        strcpy(allStudents[studentCounter].studentCountry,studentCountry);
        strcpy(allStudents[studentCounter].studentCity,studentCity);
        allStudents[studentCounter].average=(studentGrade/studentAge);
        studentCounter++;
    }else if(studentCounter>0){

        struct student bestStud=allStudents[0];
        int i=1;
        while(i < studentCounter){

            if(allStudents[i].average > bestStud.average){
                bestStud = allStudents[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s", "best student info is: ");
        printf("%d %s %f %f %s %s",
               bestStud.studentID, bestStud.studentName, bestStud.studentAge,
               bestStud.studentGrade, bestStud.studentCity, bestStud.studentCountry);
        break;
    }

}
```

}

program running should be like this:

```
Enter student info. To exit press q, then enter
3888914775 Itzel Gardner 21 26 Iran Tehran
Enter student info. To exit press q, then enter
5496060426 Korbin Murillo 4 30 Pakistan Islamabad
Enter student info. To exit press q, then enter
3845354610 Rhett Vargas 98 29 United-Kingdom London
Enter student info. To exit press q, then enter
q
best student info is: 3845354610 Rhett Vargas 98 29 United-Kingdom
London
```

I expected my output to any of these inputs to work but it always gives error.

EDIT:

my simple question im going to ask now will answer my question:

lets look at this code:

```
  char test[40];
  char current[100]="a    oday    adsa    4";
  int a;
  sscanf(current,"%[a-zA-Z -]*%d*",&test,&a);
  printf(test);
  printf(a);
```

this wont print anything but if i remove the a lets say like this :

```
  char test[40];
  char current[100]="a    oday    adsa    4";
   int a;
   sscanf(current,"%[a-zA-Z -]*",&test);
   printf(test);
```

it will work and print as required so up the output was expected to be

```
 a    oday    adsa
 4
```

but it didnt print like this actually the a was saved as 0 when i debugged it anything im missing?

Comment: You're assuming that, somehow, an `int` can hold any value.   In reality, a value like `3888914775` is too large to be stored in a 32-bit `int`  (which is a pretty common choice for an `int` type, and more than the standard requires).    If `sscanf()` fails on reading one value, it won't read the rest.   When that happens, the return value will be less than expected.    You will need to read the ID to a variable of a type that can handle larger values than an `int` can on your platform.

Comment: Did you enter tabs??

Comment: Changed it for long int, it worked for the id variable but hasn't changed anything for the other variables is there anything that im missing?
and yes im entering tabs exactly as in my example, and really thanks for the explaination of the sscanf function didn't  know that.

Comment: Edited my post to make it more simplified to answer my question.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. And, since scanf does _not_ use regular expressions, read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) - I don't think your `%[...]*` means what you think it means.

Comment: @Useless If it doesn't use regular expressions it would've not worked on what I want to do by parts, If i do each one of what im doing alone it would work its just something that im missing, I checked alot of examples and what im trying to do makes sense, you can test doing %[0-9]* or %[a-zA-Z]* and you'll see that it actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a different function like sscanf to find specific format input fields and save them?

There are plenty of scanning/parsing functions, yes. There are more standard ones in C++ than there are in C, but you can always use external libraries.

> My problem is i specified the right regex with sscanf

But as I said already, [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) **does not use regular expressions**.

I know that the `[character class]` syntax looks *similar to* regular expression syntax. It is, nevertheless, not a regex. I encourage you to read the documentation I linked which describes the syntax the `scanf` family *actually* uses.

> If it doesn't use regular expressions it would've not worked on what I want to do by parts

You're not checking your assumptions. Your assumptions are *wrong*, and you are failing to check carefully what is actually happening. This is entirely normal, and perfectly understandable, and can be a hard lesson to learn.

But you do need to learn it instead of telling the people giving you free help that you know better than them, especially when you're the one whose code doesn't work.

> ... you can test doing %[0-9]* or %[a-zA-Z]* and you'll see

Here's an experiment. Try it yourself, and refer to that documentation as you go.

- step 1: the simplest thing that could possibly work.

  Let's start by converting only the first field. We'll worry about all the rest later, and just write this according to the linked documentation.

  ```
  char tmp[100] = {};
  int rv = sscanf("a    oday    adsa    4", "%[a-zA-Z -]", tmp);
  printf("sscanf returned %d, tmp is '%s'\n", rv, tmp);
  ```

  tells me that `sscanf returned 1`, because one field was successfully scanned. That field was `%[a-zA-Z -]`, defined in the documentation and further discussed below. To confirm, the value of tmp is indeed shown as `"a    oday    adsa    "`.

  > [set] matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters

  Note there is no trailing `*`. The documentation suggests this is not needed, and we've confirmed that. We'll add it back in next to see what happens.
- step 2: what the `*` does

  ```
  char tmp[100] = {};
  int rv = sscanf("a    oday    adsa    4", "%[a-zA-Z -]*", tmp);
  printf("sscanf returned %d, tmp is '%s'\n", rv, tmp);
  ```

  tells me that `sscanf returned 1`, because one field was successfully scanned. That field was `%[a-zA-Z -]`, as before. Appending `*` to our format string didn't change the contents of `tmp` at all.

  This time we added back the `*` at the end of the format string. Reading the linked doc, you see that since it is *not* part of a `%` format specifier, and is a

  > non-whitespace multibyte characters except %: each such character in the format string consumes exactly one identical character from the input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on the stream does not compare equal.

  But so far this has *no observable effect*, because it already matched the only input field. Failure would only affect the *next* conversion, and there aren't any yet. So, let's add one in our next test.
- step 3: the effect of failure

  ```
  int val = 0;
  rv = sscanf("a    oday    adsa    4", "%[a-zA-Z -]*%d", tmp, &val);
  printf("scanf returned %d, tmp is '%s', val=%d\n", rv, tmp, val);
  ```

  tells me that `sscanf returned 1` because it converted one field *successfully*. The string output value is correct. It never converted the integer value, because there was an error before it reached `%d`, because the `*` in the format string did not match any literal `*` in the input.
- step 4: what would actually work

  ```
  int val = 0;
  rv = sscanf("a    oday    adsa    4", "%[a-zA-Z -]%d", tmp, &val);
  printf("scanf returned %d, tmp is '%s', val=%d\n", rv, tmp, val);
  ```

  tells me that `sscanf returned 2` because it converted two fields. The string and integer output values are correct.
- step 5: confirmation

  ```
  int val = 0;
  rv = sscanf("a    oday    adsa    *4", "%[a-zA-Z -]*%d", tmp, &val);
  printf("scanf returned %d, tmp is '%s', val=%d\n", rv, tmp, val);
  ```

  tells me that `sscanf returned 2` because it converted two fields. The string and integer output values are correct. Now, the literal `*` character in the format string matches the literal `*` I added to the input. This just confirms the behaviour matches the documentation.